# Question on a hypothetical cycle process in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

The maximum (theoretical) efficiency a heat-engine can get, is given by the Carnot-efficiency, i.e.

$$ e = 1 - \frac{Q_c}{Q_h} $$

It's obvious that if $ Q_c = 0$, the efficiency is $100$ %. Let us now look at the Diesel-cycle, if we leave out the isochoric step, then we would have $ Q_c = 0$, because we skipped the step where heat left the system. Of course I am wrong in my reasoning, but where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you leave out the isochoric step, then you no longer have a heat engine, because you no longer have a cycle.

Comment: Did you even draw the PV diagram for the process? If you did you’d see why you no longer have a process.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your efficiency equation applies to any heat engine cycle as it is the net work done divided by the gross heat added. For the Carnot Cycle because $Q_{c}=T_{c}\Delta S$ and $Q_{h}=T_{h}\Delta S$ the Carnot efficiency is then

$$e=1-\frac{T_c}{T_h}$$

which is the maximum efficiency for any heat engine cycle operating between two fixed thermal reservoirs.

> Of course I am wrong in my reasoning, but where am I wrong?

You are wrong because when you skip the isochoric process, you cannot complete the cycle and do *net work* over the cycle. A *process* can be 100% thermally efficient. But a cycle can't as it would violate the second law.

As pointed out by @probably_someone, for the Diesel cycle the isochoric (constant volume) process (process 4-1 in the diagram below) is necessary to return to its initial state 1 completing the cycle and performing net work, as shown by the area enclosed in the PV diagram below. Without process 4-1 to return to the initial state 1, you would need to reverse the cycle along path 4-3-2-1, for a net work of zero.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you say "skipping the isochoric process", do you mean connecting point 1 to point 3 (in Bob D's picture) directly by some kind of process? If so, remember those curves (1-2 and 3-4) are adiabatic and two adiabatic curves never cross. Two adiabatic curves crossing would mean it's possible to build a system that turns 100% of the heat taken into work, violating the 2nd law of thermodynamics.